# HeIp solve Error in React. (Uncaught TypeError: baselineData is not iterable). baselineData is clearly an array. PLEASE heIp

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-table

I am running into an issue with trying to render a table in react using react table.  I've narrowed the error down to the data variable around line 13 in figure 1.

When I hard code the data, as shown in figure 1, I have no issues and everything works fine.  This hard coded array is a direct copy of the baselineData prop being passed into the PrectionsTable component.

My error only happens when the data object is changed to as shown in figure 2.  Instead of the data being hard coded, I am spreading the baselineData prop data.

Figure 3 shows baselineData in react web dev tools and is in fact an array of objects located on the PredictionsTable.

**The specific error I am making can be seen in figure 4.**

### **Figure 1**

```js
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import React from 'react';
import SpinnerCustom from '../Spinner.js';

export default function PredictionsTable({
  predictions,
  baselineData,
  loading,
}) {
  const checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound = (x) =>
    typeof x === 'number' ? x.toFixed(2) : 'n/a';

  const data = React.useMemo(() => {
    return [
      {
        make_cut: 0.837075,
        player_name: 'Finau, Tony',
        top_10: 0.42559600288600297,
        top_20: 0.5817631080031079,
        top_5: 0.293940416666667,
        win: 0.105025,
      },
      {
        make_cut: 0.71215,
        player_name: 'Day, Jason',
        top_10: 0.228348582528583,
        top_20: 0.366261590839716,
        top_5: 0.136055932539683,
        win: 0.0341,
      },
      {
        make_cut: 0.719925,
        player_name: 'Harman, Brian',
        top_10: 0.223825056748807,
        top_20: 0.366779750145688,
        top_5: 0.12981958333333302,
        win: 0.032675,
      },
      {
        make_cut: 0.710225,
        player_name: 'Montgomery, Taylor',
        top_10: 0.21918973443223397,
        top_20: 0.352992788086097,
        top_5: 0.130785406746032,
        win: 0.0324,
      },
    ];
  }, [baselineData]);

  const columns = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: 'Player',
        accessor: 'player_name', // accessor is the "key" in the data
      },
      {
        Header: 'Make Cut',
        accessor: 'make_cut',
        Cell: (props) =>
          checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound(props.cell.row.original.make_cut),
      },
      {
        Header: 'Top 20',
        accessor: 'top_20',
        Cell: (props) =>
          checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound(props.cell.row.original.top_20),
      },
      {
        Header: 'Top 10',
        accessor: 'top_10',
        Cell: (props) =>
          checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound(props.cell.row.original.top_20),
      },
      {
        Header: 'Top 5',
        accessor: 'top_5',
        Cell: (props) =>
          checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound(props.cell.row.original.top_20),
      },
      {
        Header: 'Win',
        accessor: 'win',
        Cell: (props) =>
          checkIfValueIsNumberAndRound(props.cell.row.original.top_20),
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable({ columns, data });

  return loading ? (
    <SpinnerCustom />
  ) : (
    <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
      <thead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
              <th
                {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                style={{
                  borderBottom: 'solid 3px red',
                  background: 'aliceblue',
                  color: 'black',
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                }}
              >
                {column.render('Header')}
              </th>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </thead>

      <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
        {rows.map((row, i) => {
          prepareRow(row);

          return (
            <tr key={i} {...row.getRowProps()}>
              {row.cells.map((cell, y) => {
                return (
                  <td
                    {...cell.getCellProps()}
                    key={y}
                    style={{
                      padding: '10px',
                      border: 'solid 1px gray',
                      background: 'papayawhip',
                    }}
                  >
                    {cell.render('Cell')}
                  </td>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

### **Figure 2**

```js
  const data = React.useMemo(() => {
    return [...baselineData];
  }, [baselineData]);
```

### **Figure 3**

[image]

### **Figure 4 (ERROR)**

[image]

Comment: Spreading your baselineData does nothing in this case. Why not use the baselineData directly? Also can you please create a reproduceable example in codesandbox? Thanks

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-darwin-ucgxi0?file=/src/PredictionsTable.jsx

Comment: `const [baselineData, setBaselineData] = useState({})` your initial state has object literal. Instead of that do `useState([])`.

Comment: Rakesh, thanks bud.  Have been stuck for 8 hours on this LMAO.

Comment: happens some time.

Answer (score 1):

this problem may related to initial data for baseLineData.

change the usesState initialize:

```
const [baselineData, setBaselineData] = useState([]);
```